# Horizontally and vertically scrollable content with fixed header

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a content div with dynamic width (it adjusts itself to the windows width). In this div I have two tables which are broader than the viewport of my wrapper div. Therefore the wrapper should be horizontally scrollable. The div has also a fixed height which means that everything should be vertically scrollable too! Just the Header should stay on top but also scroll along horizontally with the content table.

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <table width="2000" class="fixed"><tr></tr></table>
    <table width="2000"><tr></tr></table>
</div>
```

Here's a fiddle to demonstrate my problem: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pDhmy/2/)

Comment: Do you mean that when the user scrolls down, then the 'header' table should always remain visible?

Comment: Yep that's what I meant! It should be scrollable both vertical and horizonzal but the header should stay on top.

Comment: Simple move the `<div class="mega">` (line 1) down to above `<table width="2000">` (line 5)

Comment: This way the header is not scrollable horizontally along with the content table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Demo:**  http://jsfiddle.net/techsin/pDhmy/4/

**Header width changes:** http://jsfiddle.net/techsin/pDhmy/8/

code that does this

`$('.mega').on('scroll',function(){$('.header').css('top',$(this).scrollTop());});`

and....

```
.header{position:absolute; background-color:rgb(202, 202, 202);}

.header+* {margin-top:30px;}
```

Comment: Nice solution but unfortunately this breaks when the content in the second "table" flows wider (e.g. http://jsfiddle.net/gvee/pDhmy/5/)... I guess we could set fixed widths to the columns?

Comment: that is because those two are different tables. This is what OP structure is. Meaning event when it was normal and scrolling with everything this would have been the case.

http://jsfiddle.net/techsin/pDhmy/6/

Comment: Adding this to the CSS mitigates the issue but is not ideal `.mega td { width: 25%; }`

Comment: I chose this structure because I didn't think using one table and manipulating the thead would work. Another problem is that I have multiple views with different tables and cell numbers. But if this is the best thing to achieve I will have to expand my backend and assign every cell of every view a specific width.

Comment: There is no need I made jquery that adjust header to width of bottom cells.
http://jsfiddle.net/techsin/pDhmy/7/

Answer (score 2):

## Sticky table headers

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/gvee/kJ9xp/

### HTML

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <th>A</th>
        <th>B</th>
        <th>C</th>
        <th>D</th>
    </thead>
    <tr class="sticky-header">
        <th>A</th>
        <th>B</th>
        <th>C</th>
        <th>D</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>

    ... etc ...

</table>
```

### CSS

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
    padding:0;
}

table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    margin: 10px;
}

th, td {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #eee;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.sticky-header {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
}
.sticky-header th {
    background-color: red;
}
```

### JQuery

```
var thead = $('thead');
var th = $('.sticky-header');
var t = $('table');

$(document).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() >= thead.offset().top && $(this).scrollTop() < t.offset().top + t.height() - th.height())
    {
        th.show();
    } else {
        th.hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: effect is nice. but there is a problem though. Each time you would need div to hit the top most part of screen. And suppose you wanted scrollable widget to scroll without scrolling the whole page. This wont work without changing the code each time. Take a look: http://jsfiddle.net/techsin/kJ9xp/2/

Comment: @MuhammadUmer I had just noticed that when playing with the code again... Thank you for the comments - I will take this back to the drawing board and try come up with a more flexible and correct solution