# How to fix vertical scrollbar inside div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

There are many answers given in stackoverflow to my question. But what is needed is can my existing code be modified or can any jQuery plugin be used.

My final result should be like [final Result with vertical overflow and table header fixed](http://www.tablefixedheader.com/fullpagedemo/)

For displaying tables i'm using HTML code

```
<div id="tables" style="width: 100%">
 <div id="divs1" style="width: 100%;margin-right:10px; float: left">
  <div style="overflow-x: auto;overflow-y: auto;border-bottom: medium none; border-left: medium none; border-top: medium none; font-weight: normal; border-right: medium none; height: 100%; width: 100%;" >
   <div style="margin-right: 0px;"> 
<table style="width: 900px;" class="div2">
 <colgroup>
  <col style="width: 115px">
  <col style="width: 180px">
  <col style="width: 180px">
  <col style="width: 180px">
 </colgroup>
 <thead>
  <tr id=rowHeader class=ui-sortable>
   <th>&nbsp;</th>
   <th><fmt:messagekey="link.Date" /></th>
   <th><fmt:messagekey="link" /></th>
   <th><fmt:messagekey="link.status" /></th>
   <th><fmt:messagekey="linkinfo" /></th>
   <th><fmt:messagekey="common.scanner" /></th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
</table>                        
   </div>
   <div style="height: 85%;overflow-x:visible;">
<div>                                   
     <table style="width: 900px;" id="divTable">
  <colgroup>
   <col style="width: 115px">
    <col style="width: 180px">
    <col style="width: 180px">
    <col style="width: 180px">
   </colgroup>
   <tbody>
   <s:iterator status="Bean" value="%{FormBean.listBean}">
    <tr>
         <td>
      <input  name="FormBean.listBean[${index}].id"value="<s:property value="id"/>" type="hidden" />
      <s:checkbox theme="simple"name="FormBean.list[%{#index}].selected"
value="selected" fieldValue="true"onclick="javascript:uncheckCheckbox(this)" /
         </td>
         <td>
          <inputstyle="width: 80px; float: left; border-style: none;"type="text" readonly="readonly" name="FormBean.listBean[${index}].Date" value='<s:property value="departureDate"/>'id="datepickerForTable[${index}]" class="sg4pInput" />
      <inputid="hiddenDate"name="FormBean.listBea [${index}].Date"value="<s:property value="Date"/>" type="hidden" />
          </td>
          <td>
           <a class="link-button ui-state-default"></a>
          </td>
      <td>
           <s:iterator status="status" value="%{FormBean.Status}" id="idStatus">
           <s:if test="FormBean.Status == #idStatus.intValue">
            <fmt:message key="${name}" />
           </s:if>
           </s:iterator>
          </td>
          <td>
           <s:property value="info" />
          </td>
          <td>
           <s:property value="Code" />
          </td>
         </tr>
        </s:iterator>
       </tbody>
      </table>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
```

I'm using like

**Case1**: using overflow to main div

**problem faced** :  Table Header is not fixed. tried every solution (position..not working)

```
<div>
  <div style="overflow: auto">
    <div>
      <table>
        <thead>.....</thead>
      </table>
    <div>
    <div style="overflow-x:visible">
     <table>
      <tbody>....</tbody>
     </table>
    </div>
    <div>
     <div>
```

**Case2** : using overflow to tbody i.e to scroll the body contents.

**problem faced** :  Vertical scrollbar is not fixed. i.e. It goes inside when we scroll by Horizontal scrollbar.

```
 <div>
  <div style="overflow-x:auto">
    <div>
      <table>
        <thead>.....</thead>
      </table>
    <div>
    <div style="overflow-x:visible;overflow-y:auto">
     <table>
      <tbody>....</tbody>
     </table>
    </div>
    <div>
     <div>
```

also tried using fixedTableHeader() plugin from this http://fixedheadertable.com/

Want to have fixed Table header and fixed vertical scroll when moving horizontal scrollbar in a `<div>` ?

Comment: What happened when you used the plugin?

Comment: Its not working. i used like below

Comment: i used like below                                jquery.fixedtableheader.js and   jquery.fixedtableheader.min.js                                   
AND in <script>  tag                                    
$(document).ready(function() {    
 $('.div2').fixedHeaderTable({ fixedColumn: true });
});                                                                  
And specified **div2 in Table header **                      
<table class="div2">  --- for fixed Header

Comment: The demo on the plugin's page uses the class for the table's body. Try applying it to the div with the "DivTable" id.

Comment: Correction: The table with the DivTable id.

Comment: @Alex : yes i'm debugging and inspecting it in Firefox using F12 (http://www.tablefixedheader.com/fullpagedemo/). Till now i'm able to fix the Vertical scrollbar when Horizontal scrollbar moving, But problrm faced is that the table header is not moving I guess its due to the Div table id in table body (it should move). But the plugin jquery.fixheadertable.min.js is not working it says jQuery is undefined at Line 1, Char 1. Don't know why

Comment: I'm using in i.e 8 browser.

Comment: the plugin is working fine but i'm not geting the desired result. the .fixheadertable() itself is combination of divs. if i put ID  in body table (it gives me another table with scrollbar and with body table inside it)

Comment: It looks like jQuery's not loading. Are you using a cdn? Sometimes I've found that you need to include the protocol ('http' or 'https') and the cdn's don't include it. On my office network, I need to specify either 'http' or 'https' when I include it using a cdn.

Comment: @Alex: Can it be possible without using any fixheadertable plugin ?  Means by using divs and table like explained above

Comment: No. I'm not using cdn, i have downloaded the jquery plugin. But i have got some idea about fixed headers from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18513300/horizontally-and-vertically-scrollable-content-with-fixed-header. But the problem i'm facing is scrollTop not working i guess. i have added 1.10.2.js jquery plugin for that. don't know why

Comment: The only way that I can think of doing this without a plugin is to use 'position: fixed'. The problem is that it pulls the element out of the document flow and it behaves as if it doesn't have a parent container. I think using a plugin would be the quickest solution.